# Is there a way to pick up the latest file to process using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to pick up the latest file to process using Azure Data Factory? The files are landing in a folder structure by year/month/day/[file1]...

In the day folder the files will land every hour and my job will also be scheduled to pick it up every hour.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you could use the [Custom-Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities),with the help of C# code you can do this.

Also you can schedule our pipeline to run for every hours basics.Since you are receiving the files in an hourly basics

Hope this Helps!